# Unable to show image in salesforce community

Tags: community

In community i want to show a image but now a href link is displayed on the community lightning component. when i click on that link then image is displayed, instead of this i want to display image without clicking on the link.

```
 <img src="https://photos.google.com/photo/someimage"></img>
```

Comment: Kindly include relevant part of your code that the community can use and test on.

Comment: do you want to show image when you hower over the link?

Comment: I have given you negative vote, because the post doesn't include necessary information to reproduce the issue. Please include include relevant part of code and I shall remove the negative vote.

Comment: I cant post my code..i have already given u all the requirment... onload i am getting url stored in rich text area field and that url is showing on the component but i want to show image instead of the url

Comment: Is that URL open. can anyone access that url?

Comment: Yes its open url

Comment: Is the image stored in the RichTextArea field as an image or url?

Comment: as url it is stored

Comment: Won't work that way. Either you have to store it as an image in the richtext area field or store it separately in the Salesforce Files.

Comment: Check the field level security.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have stored the image in your [`RichTextArea`](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=fields_rich_text_area_limitations.htm&type=5) field as image not text URL.

To show the image you can either use [`<ui:outputRichText>`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/ui:outputRichText/documentation) or [`<lightning:formattedRichTex>`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:formattedRichText/example)

e.g.
`<ui:outputRichText aura:id="image" value="{! record.RichTextAreaField }" />`

Finally, to overcome the permissions error, check field-level security of the field and verify if you have appropriate permissions to the field.